# Typescript data filtering on nested array based on another array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array, filter

Im new to TS
I have an array of data that looks like this

```
const AllJobs = [
      {
        title: Teller,
        salary: ["Hourly"],
        industries: [
          "Accounting",
          "Banking",
          "Data"
        ]
      },
      {
        title: Scientist,
        salary: ["Yearly"],
        industries: [
          "Biology",
          "Chemicals",
          "Science"
        ]
      },
        {
        title: Artist,
        salary: ["Hourly"],
        industries: [
          "Design",
          "Paint",
          "Color"
        ]
      },
    ];

let desiredSkills = ["Design","Accounting","Data"];
```

I want to loop over a the data in the "industries" in the AllJobs array and check if any of those vales match any of the values in desiredSkills. If no matching values, filter out that object. I don't know if im doing this right at all.

Desired results:

```
 const AllJobs = [
          {
            title: Teller,
            salary: ["Hourly"],
            industries: [
              "Accounting",
              "Banking",
              "Data"
            ]
          },
            {
            title: Artist,
            salary: ["Hourly"],
            industries: [
              "Design",
              "Paint",
              "Color"
            ]
          },
        ];
```

Here is my previous code. That is currently not working.

```
const getSuggested = (item: string) => {
   const filterIndustry = this.allJobs.filter((x:any) => x['industries'].every((y: string | any[])=> y.includes(item)));
  };
this.desiredIndustries.forEach(getSuggested);
```

I have also tried

```
 const getSuggested = (item: string) => {
 let k = item;

 const data = this.allJobs.filter((item: { industries: any }) => item.industries == k);
 console.log(data);
 };
 this.desiredIndustries.forEach(getSuggested);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need TypeScript here, so here's a JS solution for you:

```js
const AllJobs = [{
    title: 'Teller',
    salary: ['Hourly'],
    industries: ['Accounting', 'Banking', 'Data'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Scientist',
    salary: ['Yearly'],
    industries: ['Biology', 'Chemicals', 'Science'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Artist',
    salary: ['Hourly'],
    industries: ['Design', 'Paint', 'Color'],
  },
];

let desiredSkills = ['Design', 'Accounting', 'Data'];

const result = AllJobs.filter(({
  industries
}) => industries.find((industry) => desiredSkills.includes(industry)));

console.log(result);
```

Should be easy to translate to TS. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. My only questions is what is 'industries' in the first {} referring to? I ask because TS is throwing a syntax fit about not it being typecast. I give it the type of 'any' and it still won't work.  I pretty sure it is referring the the  object key but I don't understand why it is an error and not allowing it to compile.

The error says "Binding element 'industries' implicitly has an 'any' type".

Comment: It's the same as doing `AllJobs.filter((job) => job.industries.find...`, I just used object destructuring there to make it simpler. Please consider upvoting and/or accepting if the answer helped, cheers!